# How to animate background image on click event

Tags: jquery, background

I am trying to have smooth transition effect when user click to chose different background image with below jquery code but it doesn't seems to work. I want to animate only background image not content of the page.

```
$('.bg1').click(function() {
    ($this).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
    $(this)
        .css({'background-image': 'url(img/bg-2.jpg)'})
        .animate({opacity: 1});
     });
});
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/Tw8Ph/4

Comment: `$this` is it a variable you're using? or missing `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use `$this` a lot, so i would recommend you to put it in `var`

```
$('.bg1').click(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
    $this
        .css({'background-image': 'url(img/bg-2.jpg)'})
        .animate({opacity: 1});
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is small misatke in your code

**HTML CODE:**

```
$('.bg1').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {  
    $(this)
    .css({'background-image': 'url(img/bg-2.jpg)'})
    .animate({opacity: 1});
 });
});
```

you have made a mistake on line 2 instead of  `($this).animate({opacity: 0},` it should be `$(this).animate({opacity: 0},` .

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks. I want to switch background image when user click on different buttons. Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tw8Ph/4/

Comment: I don't want body content to animate only background image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set css background-image of the body and not use this which refers to the clicked button.
But your last fiddle seems to look just fine to me. The only mistake is the third button has been affected with the wrong css class.

`$('body').css('background-image','url(source)');`

http://jsfiddle.net/Tw8Ph/6/